# Google+1 Button API Callback Not Working after Google Update

Tags: javascript, google-plus, google-plus-one

My callback "onPlus" on Google+1 button from external website does not work anymore after the latest update of Google of removing the counts on Google+1 button.

See 
https://plus.google.com/110610523830483756510/posts/Z1FfzduveUo

My Code

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<div class="g-plusone" data-href="http://sample.com/" data-autoclose="true" data-recommendations="false" data-callback="onPlus"></div>
```

Is there any way to bring back the callback feature?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue :(

Comment: So do I :/  Anyone knows what to do ?